# Select from DB and submit form

Tags: php

I have a table with fruits (fid,fname,fgram).I am selecting the fruit name on my php code and i try while i show to the user the first name if he input the correct fruit name to go on to the second name and so on.
The code i am trying to use in php  is :

```
$result=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT fname FROM fruits") or 
 die(mysqli_connect_errno());
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $check=$_SESSION['submit'];

  $resultname=$row[0];

  if($check=$resultname){
    echo " $resultname" ;
  }
}
```

Can someone point me the mistake i make? 
This is one of my first Questions sorry if the formation is not correct,
Thanks.

Comment: here `if($check=$resultname)` you're assigning, not camparing! use `==` (or `===` for strict) to compare.

Comment: The mistake you have made: You're using 1 `=` to check the variable, `=` is an **assignment** operator. You're just setting `$check` to the contents of `$resultname`. Use `==` instead.

Comment: `mysqli_connect_errno()` won't help you, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php is the function for query errors. You'd be better to use a `where` clause on your query. `SELECT fname FROM fruits where fname = ?` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Aside from the error mentioned above, I don't see the _point_ of this code.  If the `=` vs `==` issue is fixed, all this really seems to do is echo the input value _if it exists in the db_.  If that's really what you want to do, it would be better to adjust the query to include a `WHERE` clause and then check if a row is returned.  This (in most cases) would be more efficient than pulling all rows and looping through them.